# JQuery load multiple url's and return only one deferred at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I've a array of url's. I like to load each of them and append the content to the element.

```
var myStrArray = ["http://www.google.de", "http://www.facebook.de", "http://www.lycos.de"];

//Initialize local deferred for myStrArray 
var myDeferredArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myStrArray; i++)
{
   myDeferredArray[i] = $.Deferred();
}

for (var i = 0; i < myStrArray.length; i++)
{
   $(element).load(myStrArray, function() {
       doSomething();
       myDeferredArray[i].resolve();
   });
}

return myDeferredArray as single deferred
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get a single deferred

```
$.when.apply(null, deferreds);
```